# Triple integration, a general question

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

If the triple integral of the function g is equivalent to the triple integral of the function w, is it the case that g=w?

Comment: I don't believe this is a necessary consequence. Do you have any more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course not. Take a function $f(x,y,z)$ such that $f(-x,y,z) = -f(x,y,z)$. Consider $D = \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3 \, | \, \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} \le 1 \}$. Then
$$
\iiint_D f(x,y,z) \, dx \, dy \, dz = 0 = \iiint_D 0 \, dx \, dy \, dz 
$$
using the classical symmetry argument. But $f$ doesn't have to be zero! Take for instance $f(x,y,z) = \sin(x)$.

Hope that helps,